# Is this a good way to transform a multi level deep array of objects to a concise array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've got a large array of objects where each object has a key with an array of objects (and from there another level deep), retrieved from a Firestore database. It looks like this:
There are multiple rayons (or areas) where each rayon is an object. Each rayon can have none, one, or many measuring points (array of objects). Each measuring point can have none, one, or many measurements. Each measurement has a UNIX date for when it was created. For each rayon, I need to acquire the measurement with the latest date and I need to know in which measuring point that was.

In this image you can see that I've got it working.
[image]
If a  rayon has no measuring points, it displays a dash instead.

The code for transforming it is as follows (with the array of objects and the result).

```js
const rayons = [
  {
    "uid": "1///rayons/FaexjdCxsYECRVTghU6R",
    "measuring_points": [
      {
        "uid": "1///rayons/FaexjdCxsYECRVTghU6R/measuring_points/LCkJoEt6oCkPYKqC3i27",
        "measurements": [
          {
            "uid": "1///rayons/FaexjdCxsYECRVTghU6R/measuring_points/LCkJoEt6oCkPYKqC3i27/measurements/sT7ar4ezHWdGPJnNmm2C",
            "added_by": "i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2",
            "date_added": {
              "seconds": 1554804000,
              "nanoseconds": 0
            },
            "ice_thickness": 1.5,
            "is_deleted": false,
            "notes": "Snow was yellow for some reason",
            "snow_height": 5
          },
          {
            "uid": "1///rayons/FaexjdCxsYECRVTghU6R/measuring_points/LCkJoEt6oCkPYKqC3i27/measurements/sFglNwTUYU1mKXREyjen",
            "added_by": "i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2",
            "date_added": {
              "seconds": 1544883008,
              "nanoseconds": 241000000
            },
            "ice_thickness": 2,
            "is_deleted": false,
            "notes": "een opmerking",
            "snow_height": 3
          }
        ],
        "added_by": "i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2",
        "is_deleted": false,
        "location": {
          "_lat": 52.9416192,
          "_long": 5.8114048
        },
        "name": "Main Point Balk"
      }
    ],
    "name": "Balk",
    "users": [
      "i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2",
      "6Ijf3gKvLghET8yCEfaC1iAbi0j1",
      "uyUR2xVvlvWMpV1J2OClOeUILwM2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "uid": "1///rayons/oKKKMTAdtinC34Mui3R0",
    "measuring_points": [
      {
        "uid": "1///rayons/oKKKMTAdtinC34Mui3R0/measuring_points/Hc72pD4nPZoAO8xYXIVo",
        "measurements": [
          {
            "uid": "1///rayons/oKKKMTAdtinC34Mui3R0/measuring_points/Hc72pD4nPZoAO8xYXIVo/measurements/ufhxEaVAvTOiUAxEuah3",
            "added_by": "i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2",
            "date_added": {
              "seconds": 1548621505,
              "nanoseconds": 90000000
            },
            "ice_thickness": 0.5,
            "is_deleted": false,
            "notes": "",
            "snow_height": 0
          }
        ],
        "added_by": "i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2",
        "is_deleted": false,
        "location": {
          "_lat": 52.941685299999996,
          "_long": 5.8107096
        },
        "name": "1.2 Test"
      },
      {
        "uid": "1///rayons/oKKKMTAdtinC34Mui3R0/measuring_points/HfZ0Mxq7lkvq1HWp4iP9",
        "measurements": [
          {
            "uid": "1///rayons/oKKKMTAdtinC34Mui3R0/measuring_points/HfZ0Mxq7lkvq1HWp4iP9/measurements/kGg3xcMHWjZhYwJ8sGXc",
            "added_by": "i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2",
            "date_added": {
              "seconds": 1548621856,
              "nanoseconds": 502000000
            },
            "ice_thickness": 11,
            "is_deleted": false,
            "notes": "",
            "snow_height": 0
          },
          {
            "uid": "1///rayons/oKKKMTAdtinC34Mui3R0/measuring_points/HfZ0Mxq7lkvq1HWp4iP9/measurements/QYCJZIfgtYh0CdzgT99f",
            "added_by": "i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2",
            "date_added": {
              "seconds": 1548605585,
              "nanoseconds": 992000000
            },
            "ice_thickness": 1.5,
            "is_deleted": false,
            "notes": "",
            "snow_height": 0
          }
        ],
        "added_by": "i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2",
        "is_deleted": false,
        "location": {
          "_lat": 52.941685299999996,
          "_long": 5.8107096
        },
        "name": "1.1 Test"
      },
      {
        "uid": "1///rayons/oKKKMTAdtinC34Mui3R0/measuring_points/yc64NpCFeln4sQQjeXef",
        "measurements": [],
        "added_by": "i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2",
        "is_deleted": false,
        "location": {
          "_lat": 52.941685299999996,
          "_long": 5.8107096
        },
        "name": "1.10 Test"
      }
    ],
    "name": "Joure",
    "users": []
  },
  {
    "uid": "1///rayons/H20FJdCAP7WR1CYUCXdQ",
    "measuring_points": [
      {
        "uid": "1///rayons/H20FJdCAP7WR1CYUCXdQ/measuring_points/9Lwbaf9UnHDONkF78uIb",
        "measurements": [
          {
            "uid": "1///rayons/H20FJdCAP7WR1CYUCXdQ/measuring_points/9Lwbaf9UnHDONkF78uIb/measurements/6b7kMXQISqzaHMYGhMwc",
            "added_by": "i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2",
            "date_added": {
              "seconds": 1548620524,
              "nanoseconds": 55000000
            },
            "ice_thickness": 6,
            "is_deleted": false,
            "notes": "",
            "snow_height": 0
          }
        ],
        "added_by": "i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2",
        "is_deleted": false,
        "location": {
          "_lat": 53.197598005739415,
          "_long": 5.757791419036211
        },
        "name": "Ferbiningskanaal"
      },
      {
        "uid": "1///rayons/H20FJdCAP7WR1CYUCXdQ/measuring_points/p2Z71ttO8UBDmUacezIU",
        "measurements": [
          {
            "uid": "1///rayons/H20FJdCAP7WR1CYUCXdQ/measuring_points/p2Z71ttO8UBDmUacezIU/measurements/Edb6Zr7pVnS16odfmNew",
            "added_by": "i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2",
            "date_added": {
              "seconds": 1541761200,
              "nanoseconds": 0
            },
            "ice_thickness": 2,
            "is_deleted": false,
            "notes": "",
            "snow_height": 0
          }
        ],
        "added_by": "i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2",
        "is_deleted": false,
        "location": {
          "_lat": 52.370215699999996,
          "_long": 4.895167900000001
        },
        "name": "Leeuwarden Centrum"
      }
    ],
    "name": "Leeuwarden",
    "users": [
      ""
    ]
  },
  {
    "uid": "1///rayons/ffBCDYi8xRkFOkbS4Gk7",
    "measuring_points": [],
    "name": "Munnekeburen",
    "users": []
  }
]

const result = rayons
  .map(({ name: rayon, measuring_points }) => {
      // Bail early.
      if (!measuring_points.length)
          return {
              rayon,
              measuring_point: '-',
              date: '-',
              ice_thickness: '-',
          }

      // Check if there's a single measuring point.
      if (measuring_points.length && measuring_points.length === 1) {
          // Go through all measuring points and return an array with one object.
          let array = measuring_points.reduce((accumulator, { name: measuring_point, measurements }) => {
              // Bail early.
              if (!measurements.length) return

              let newestMeasurementCleaned = {}
              // Check if there's a single measurement.
              if (measurements.length === 1) {
                  // Return the first and only measurement with the names of the rayon and measuring point.
                  let {
                      date_added: { seconds: date },
                      ice_thickness,
                  } = measurements[0]

                  newestMeasurementCleaned = {
                      rayon,
                      measuring_point,
                      date,
                      ice_thickness,
                  }
              // Check if there's more than one measurement.
              } else if (measurements.length > 1) {
                  // Return the measurement with the newest date and the names of the rayon and measuring point.
                  let {
                      date_added: { seconds: date },
                      ice_thickness,
                  } = measurements.reduce(
                      (prev, curr) => {
                          return prev.date_added.seconds > curr.date_added.seconds ? prev : curr
                      },
                      { date_added: { seconds: 0 } }
                  )

                  newestMeasurementCleaned = {
                      rayon,
                      measuring_point,
                      date,
                      ice_thickness,
                  }
              }
              return accumulator.concat(newestMeasurementCleaned)
          }, [])
          return array[0]
      // Check if there's more than one single measuring point.
      } else if (measuring_points.length && measuring_points.length > 1) {
          // Go through all measuring points, filter out undefined and return a single object.
          let object = measuring_points
              .map(({ name: measuring_point, measurements }) => {
                  // Bail early.
                  if (!measurements.length) return

                  let newestMeasurementCleaned = {}
                  // Check if there's a single measurement.
                  if (measurements.length === 1) {
                      // Return the first and only measurement with the names of the rayon and measuring point.
                      let {
                          date_added: { seconds: date },
                          ice_thickness,
                      } = measurements[0]

                      newestMeasurementCleaned = {
                          rayon,
                          measuring_point,
                          date,
                          ice_thickness,
                      }
                  // Check if there's more than one measurement.
                  } else if (measurements.length > 1) {
                      // Return the measurement with the newest date and the names of the rayon and measuring point.
                      let {
                          date_added: { seconds: date },
                          ice_thickness,
                      } = measurements.reduce(
                          (prev, curr) => {
                              return prev.date_added.seconds > curr.date_added.seconds ? prev : curr
                          },
                          { date_added: { seconds: 0 } }
                      )

                      newestMeasurementCleaned = {
                          rayon,
                          measuring_point,
                          date,
                          ice_thickness,
                      }
                  }
                  return newestMeasurementCleaned
              })
              .filter(item => typeof item !== 'undefined')
              .reduce(
                  (prev, curr) => {
                      return prev.date > curr.date ? prev : curr
                  },
                  { date: 0 }
              )
          return object
      }
  })
  .filter(item => typeof item !== 'undefined')

 console.log(result)
```

My question is, is this a good way to do this, or is there a better, easier, or more concise way to do this? I'm not new to Javascript, but I'm always curious to get to know better ways to solve questions like this.

Comment: At an initial glance, there's definitely some redundant checks that could be removed for `measurements.length` in particular. Still looking through the rest of it.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! I'm curious for the rest of your findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code definitely has a lot of redundant checks. Don't write unnecessary base-cases for lengths 0 and 1 that your last branch should be able to handle by itself. The performance improvement is negligible compared to the improved readability of having [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) code. If you find later that your program is taking too long for the dataset you're reducing, *then* you can profile your code and determine what implementations to optimize.

```js
const rayons = [{uid:'1///rayons/FaexjdCxsYECRVTghU6R',measuring_points:[{uid:'1///rayons/FaexjdCxsYECRVTghU6R/measuring_points/LCkJoEt6oCkPYKqC3i27',measurements:[{uid:'1///rayons/FaexjdCxsYECRVTghU6R/measuring_points/LCkJoEt6oCkPYKqC3i27/measurements/sT7ar4ezHWdGPJnNmm2C',added_by:'i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2',date_added:{seconds:1554804000,nanoseconds:0},ice_thickness:1.5,is_deleted:false,notes:'Snow was yellow for some reason',snow_height:5},{uid:'1///rayons/FaexjdCxsYECRVTghU6R/measuring_points/LCkJoEt6oCkPYKqC3i27/measurements/sFglNwTUYU1mKXREyjen',added_by:'i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2',date_added:{seconds:1544883008,nanoseconds:241000000},ice_thickness:2,is_deleted:false,notes:'een opmerking',snow_height:3}],added_by:'i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2',is_deleted:false,location:{_lat:52.9416192,_long:5.8114048},name:'Main Point Balk'}],name:'Balk',users:['i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2','6Ijf3gKvLghET8yCEfaC1iAbi0j1','uyUR2xVvlvWMpV1J2OClOeUILwM2']},{uid:'1///rayons/oKKKMTAdtinC34Mui3R0',measuring_points:[{uid:'1///rayons/oKKKMTAdtinC34Mui3R0/measuring_points/Hc72pD4nPZoAO8xYXIVo',measurements:[{uid:'1///rayons/oKKKMTAdtinC34Mui3R0/measuring_points/Hc72pD4nPZoAO8xYXIVo/measurements/ufhxEaVAvTOiUAxEuah3',added_by:'i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2',date_added:{seconds:1548621505,nanoseconds:90000000},ice_thickness:0.5,is_deleted:false,notes:'',snow_height:0}],added_by:'i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2',is_deleted:false,location:{_lat:52.941685299999996,_long:5.8107096},name:'1.2 Test'},{uid:'1///rayons/oKKKMTAdtinC34Mui3R0/measuring_points/HfZ0Mxq7lkvq1HWp4iP9',measurements:[{uid:'1///rayons/oKKKMTAdtinC34Mui3R0/measuring_points/HfZ0Mxq7lkvq1HWp4iP9/measurements/kGg3xcMHWjZhYwJ8sGXc',added_by:'i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2',date_added:{seconds:1548621856,nanoseconds:502000000},ice_thickness:11,is_deleted:false,notes:'',snow_height:0},{uid:'1///rayons/oKKKMTAdtinC34Mui3R0/measuring_points/HfZ0Mxq7lkvq1HWp4iP9/measurements/QYCJZIfgtYh0CdzgT99f',added_by:'i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2',date_added:{seconds:1548605585,nanoseconds:992000000},ice_thickness:1.5,is_deleted:false,notes:'',snow_height:0}],added_by:'i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2',is_deleted:false,location:{_lat:52.941685299999996,_long:5.8107096},name:'1.1 Test'},{uid:'1///rayons/oKKKMTAdtinC34Mui3R0/measuring_points/yc64NpCFeln4sQQjeXef',measurements:[],added_by:'i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2',is_deleted:false,location:{_lat:52.941685299999996,_long:5.8107096},name:'1.10 Test'}],name:'Joure',users:[]},{uid:'1///rayons/H20FJdCAP7WR1CYUCXdQ',measuring_points:[{uid:'1///rayons/H20FJdCAP7WR1CYUCXdQ/measuring_points/9Lwbaf9UnHDONkF78uIb',measurements:[{uid:'1///rayons/H20FJdCAP7WR1CYUCXdQ/measuring_points/9Lwbaf9UnHDONkF78uIb/measurements/6b7kMXQISqzaHMYGhMwc',added_by:'i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2',date_added:{seconds:1548620524,nanoseconds:55000000},ice_thickness:6,is_deleted:false,notes:'',snow_height:0}],added_by:'i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2',is_deleted:false,location:{_lat:53.197598005739415,_long:5.757791419036211},name:'Ferbiningskanaal'},{uid:'1///rayons/H20FJdCAP7WR1CYUCXdQ/measuring_points/p2Z71ttO8UBDmUacezIU',measurements:[{uid:'1///rayons/H20FJdCAP7WR1CYUCXdQ/measuring_points/p2Z71ttO8UBDmUacezIU/measurements/Edb6Zr7pVnS16odfmNew',added_by:'i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2',date_added:{seconds:1541761200,nanoseconds:0},ice_thickness:2,is_deleted:false,notes:'',snow_height:0}],added_by:'i7gvYo3W9UQynanw1xDXnOOAImk2',is_deleted:false,location:{_lat:52.370215699999996,_long:4.895167900000001},name:'Leeuwarden Centrum'}],name:'Leeuwarden',users:['']},{uid:'1///rayons/ffBCDYi8xRkFOkbS4Gk7',measuring_points:[],name:'Munnekeburen',users:[]}]

const result = rayons.map(({ name: rayon, measuring_points }) =>
  measuring_points.reduce((acc, { name: measuring_point, measurements }) => {
    const measurement = measurements.reduce(
      (acc, { date_added: { seconds: date }, ice_thickness }) => acc.date >= date
        ? acc
        : { rayon, measuring_point, date, ice_thickness },
      { rayon, measuring_point, date: -Infinity, ice_thickness: '-' }
    )

    return acc.date >= measurement.date
      ? acc
      : measurement
  }, {
    rayon,
    measuring_point: '-',
    date: null,
    ice_thickness: '-'
  })
).map(rayon => {
  if (rayon.date === null) rayon.date = '-'
  return rayon
})

console.log(result)
```

For the date comparisons, `null` is equivalent to using `0`, but it can be checked explicitly for mapping to `'-'` after finishing the reduction of measuring points. The initial value for the inner accumulator has a date of `-Infinity`, which is less than `null` or any numeric value, so that if the `measurements` is empty, then the comparison still prefers the `measuring_point: '-'` over the labeled measuring point with no measurements.

Comment: This is great! I took a few minutes to understand what is going on, and I can say that this is something I probably wouldn't have come up with with my skill level. Thanks for this; I learned something new! :)

Comment: @ArjendeJong glad to help